# Airflow: having an operator trigger on multiple trigger rules

Tags: python, airflow

I'm currently writing up an operator as follows to run at the end of my graph

```
fail = DummyOperator(
    task_id=t_fail,
    default_args=args,
    trigger_rule='one_failed',
    on_success_callback=partial(dag_complete_notification,
    dag_success=reference.DagCompleteStatus.INCOMPLETE),
    dag=dag
)
```

Ideally I'd to trigger the operator only when all of its upstreams are complete, and if one of them failed.

`Base_Operator` only accepts a single argument for trigger rule unfortunately, even though I'd really like to just write `one_failed and all_complete`.

Are there alternatives for how to approach this?

Edit: out of date as the question applied to Airflow 1.1.2.

Comment: Did you be able to find solution for your question ? if yes can you please post your answer.

Comment: Oh god this is so old and I worded the question so incorrectly haha.

Long story short this question was for Airflow version 1.1.02 and I believe the behavior of all the operator classes AND scheduling/triggering has advanced *significantly* in Airflow 2.1.x.  The rubbish with requiring a whole bunch of functools.partial to overload in particular is hopefully no longer needed.   My problem was failure notifications triggering before the entire graph finished specifically.

Comment: My 5 minute answer is that figuring out "cascading" logic with Airflow conditions was non-trivial in the past, and no we never solved it in 1.1.02.  We're migrating to 2.1.x now which is an entirely different world, but this question doesn't apply there.